# How to get user id?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jsf-2

How can I get user id (i.e., windows login user id) with out being passed it from client code but retrieve it on the server in a web application? I want this to identify user roles.
Can any one help on priority?

Answer (score -2):

I think you are asking about the Operating System's name.. You can get that using "Instance". then every time who ever visits you website will be/can be greeted by his or her computer name..

Comment: Computer name?? Can you place a sample code so I can verify if that works for me?